# complete scrollView screenshot not completely visible android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to take full `scrollView` screenshot of a `fragment` in android. What seems to be working for other doesn't work in my case. I referred to other stackoverflow questions as well. Only bottom part of the screenshot is visible and top part is missing and in the middle it is black (screenshot attached below).

```
Bitmap bitmap = createScreenshot(mainLinearLayout, mainLinearLayout.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), mainScrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth());

 //create bitmap from the ScrollView
private Bitmap createScreenshot(View view, int height, int width) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar_eco_scan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="@dimen/progressbar_elevation"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_ecoScan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:padding="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_24sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_eco_scan_top_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- fragment title & desc -->
            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView_home_plant_scan"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius_default">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_5sdp"
                        android:text="@string/my_personal_eco_scan"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_header"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/garten_von"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_medium"
                            android:textStyle="italic" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_view_eco_scan_garden_owner_label"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_5sdp"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_medium"
                            android:textStyle="italic" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_eco_scan_date_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_medium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_eco_scan_about_desc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                        android:lines="4"
                        android:text="@string/eco_scan_description"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_small" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/expand_icon_eco_scan_desc"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/expand"
                        android:text="@string/more_details"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_medium" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/greenIntensity4"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius_default">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_eco_scan_surface_label"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_5sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:lines="2"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText_eco_scan_surface"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                        android:minWidth="@dimen/editText_min_width" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_5sdp"
                        android:text="@string/meter_squared"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/greenIntensity4"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius_default">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_eco_scan_green_area_label"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_5sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:lines="2"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editText_eco_scan_green_area"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.2"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                        android:minWidth="@dimen/editText_min_width" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_5sdp"
                        android:text="@string/meter_squared"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius_default">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:text="@string/auswertung"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_header"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <!-- land use slider -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/land_use"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_medium" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image_view_eco_scan_land_use_info"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
                            app:tint="@color/darkGray" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekbar_eco_scan_land_use"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/seek_bar_height"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:splitTrack="false"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_eco_thumb_icon" />

                    <!-- Eco element slider -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/eco_element"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_medium" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image_view_eco_scan_eco_element_info"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
                            app:tint="@color/darkGray" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekbar_eco_scan_eco_element"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/seek_bar_height"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:splitTrack="false"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_eco_thumb_icon" />

                    <!-- Plant diversity slider -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/plant_diversity"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_medium" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image_view_eco_scan_plant_diversity_info"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
                            app:tint="@color/darkGray" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekbar_eco_scan_plant_diversity"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/seek_bar_height"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:paddingStart="0dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:splitTrack="false"
                        android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_eco_thumb_icon" />

                    <!-- Flowering time slider -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/flowering_time"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_medium" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image_view_eco_scan_flowering_time_info"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
                            app:tint="@color/darkGray" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart
                        android:id="@+id/combined_chart_eco_scan"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/chart_height"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                    <!-- legends -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/small_icon_size"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/small_icon_size"
                            android:src="@drawable/oko_optimum_gartengroesse_icon" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                            android:text="@string/optimal_for_your_garden_size"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_small" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_5sdp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/small_icon_size"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/small_icon_size"
                            android:src="@drawable/oko_anzahl_meiner_bluehenden_arten_icon" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                            android:text="@string/number_of_flowering_species"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_small" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_5sdp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/small_icon_size"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/small_icon_size"
                            android:src="@drawable/oko_optimum_erreicht_icon" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                            android:text="@string/optimum_achieved"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_body_small" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/button_eco_scan_save_result_to_calendar"
                        style="@style/PrimaryButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_10sdp"
                        android:text="@string/save_result_to_calendar" />

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/button_eco_scan_share_result"
                        style="@style/SecondaryButtonStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginPaddingSize_24sdp"
                        android:text="@string/share_result" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should draw the content of the ScrollView (the view having id linear_layout_eco_scan_top_view) instead. The missing content is due to memory optimizations made by the ScrollView which draws only the views that fit on the screen and skips the others (you should ensure the bitmap fits in the available memory of your app before creating it to prevent an OutOfMemoryError).

Comment: yes exactly that was the issue i wasn't aware of scrollview memory optimization. Thank you, much appreciated.